# C macros, what's the meaning of ((void)0)?

Tags: c, macros, c99, void

Given the following code written according to the C99 standard:

```
#define LOW 1 
#define MEDIUM 2 
#define HIGH 3

#define LOGGING_LEVEL HIGH

#if LOGGING_LEVEL >= MEDIUM
#define LOG_MEDIUM(message) printf(message) 
#else
#define LOG_MEDIUM(message) ((void)0) 
#endif

void load_configuration() { 
//...
LOG_MEDIUM("Configuration loaded\n"); 
}
```

what's the purpose of `((void)0)` I searched the web a lot but nothing found regarding this.

Plus, why didn't we wrote `;` after using `printf(message)`

Comment: That is no operation .

Comment: It's just creating a void-valued result.  The `0` is just a dummy value, since the cast needs to be applied to an expression.  The void cast discards the value.  You can think of the entire thing as a void-valued constant expression.

Comment: @TomKarzes ok but why we need a void-valued constant expression at first place?

Comment: @Chris1998ch I think they just want to prevent people from trying to use the result.  It's not a very good example, since `printf` returns an `int` so it's inconsistent.

Comment: Also, the reason they left the semicolon `;` out of the macros is that the user can add it.  Otherwise, if they had the semicolon and the user added a second one, it would become a sequence of statements and could be a syntax problem, e.g. `if (c) MACRO; else x;` would expand as `if (c) expr;; else x;` which would be a syntax error due to the double semicolons `;;`.

Comment: But we can always but a semicolon and there is no reasons for him to add one @TomKarzes

Comment: @Chris1998ch Look at my example again.  It will give a syntax error with the extra semicolon.  Try it.  It terminates the `if` statement, and the `else` is left with nothing to match.  Syntax error.  *Try it*.  It is *very* common practice for C macros to be written in such a way that a semicolon is *required* to terminate them.  That's why you see macro bodies with `do { ...} while (0)` in them so often - it consumes a semicolon that the user must supply, which `{ ... }` doesn't.

Comment: @Chris1998ch Oh, I think Thomas Dickey has a good explanation for the `void` cast.  Making it void-valued avoids a warning about a statement with no effect.  I'm sure that's why they use `((void) 0)` instead of just `(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

The void-cast fixes a compiler warning.  Here's an analogous testcase:

```
int main(void)
{
        0; // generates "foo.c:3:2: warning: statement with no effect"
        (void)0;
        return 0;
}
```

and (using a [script](https://invisible-island.net/personal/lint-tools.html#tool_gcc) to add gcc's warning flags) you see a warning for the line without a cast:

```
$ gcc-stricter -c foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:3:2: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
  0;
  ^
```

The extra parentheses and lack of semicolon allow the macro's result to be used interchangeably with the `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is to exclude all `LOG_MEDIUM` if the criteria was not meet.
After compilation those calls will not affect functionality.